# Select like another field value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm searching a way to compare two columns with the "like" operator, but having the wildcar inside the value.

So if I have a table1:

```
value
dog%
%cat
some%value
```

And table2:

```
value
doggy
someothervalue
cat1
```

This query:

```
select * from table1, table2 where table2.value like table1.value
```

Should return "doggy" and "someothervalue"

It is not possible?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. See [this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbd35/2).

Comment: I had the like operands reversed in my code... Thank you very much for the help!